# Make Network Manager reconfigure routing

Tags: networkmanager

I set up a very crude Internet restriction: Between 8pm and 6am, cron will `ip route delete default` every minute. This works really well. Now I have to ensure that Internet magically comes back at 6am.

To that end I would like to define another cron job, which makes Network Manager restore the default route, every minute between 6am and 7am. I think I could simply call `dhclient` every minute, but I don't know how Network Manager would react to that. I would like to be able to send some event to Network Manager, so that it notices the missing default route and restores it from its current state. Is there such an event for Network Manager? How can I trigger it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `nmcli device reapply "$DEVICE"`.

Alternatively, you can also reactivate the profile. That is more intrusive as it takes the interface down for a moment. You do that either with `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE"`, or alternatively `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE" ifname "$DEVICE"` or `nmcli device connect "$DEVICE"`.

Of course, you can also use other NetworkManager client tools instead of `nmcli`. But `nmcli` seems most suitable here.

See `man nmcli`.

Btw, I find the cron job to do this every minute a bit odd. Maybe a different solution would be better... but that wasn't the question :)